# Looking to add a SharePoint list that is used to gather requests for tasks and notify upon completion

Tags: sharepoint-online

So I am working on a SharePoint list that is to work as a database for inspection requests. Along with all the information of the request, in the list there will be three columns that each specify the name of a person(engineer) on the network that is linked to the request. I would like these people to be email notified when submitting a new request and also be notified upon Approval/Rejection of the inspection. I am very new to SharePoint online and am not sure what the correct direction would be for this. I've heard there is built in task completion functions within SharePoint but am unsure if this would be ideal for my situation or how it would work(as a column or some external workflow or what)? Can anyone help lead me on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a workflow, I think this will help you out:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-flow-for-a-list-or-library-in-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business-a9c3e03b-0654-46af-a254-20252e580d01

Comment: I have figured out how to send an email upon creating a new request but I am not sure how to do it for when there is changes made to the 'Status' of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workflow to be triggered when a new item is modified. And use an if condition to check the status column. If the status column is approved/rejected. 
[image]